# Multiple Targets Sharing Files

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8-today-widget, today-extension

I have an iOS application (Single View Application) which I created back in 2012. Now, I want to add "Todays Extension" target to the solution. I have added Todays Extension as a separate target. The problem I am facing is that I cannot use any of the files that I added in my original project.

Even if I import the headers I still cannot instantiate classes which belonged to my original project. How can I share classes between the two targets.

**MAIN ISSUE:**

The main issue is that I create a SQLITE database in the default target. The database is stored in the Documents directory of the main app. The problem is that the Todays Extension cannot access that directory and even if I save the path in the NSUserDefaults it still cannot access it.

Comment: Are there any errors associated with your importing the headers? What specific error message/issue is preventing you from instantiating the classes from your original project?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check in your inspector the file to share it with your Today extension target.

[image]
Select your .m file, and in the right col (the inspector) you can check the "Target Membership" of the file. Simply add it to your extension too. 
(In the picture above, Weather Live - Suisse is a today extension and the other target regulare apps).

Comment: Thanks! I will try it. I changed Target Membership of one class to have the Todays Extension but it calls several other classes so looks like I have to add a lot of classes manually to the Todays Extension target.

Comment: Yes sometimes it's pretty anoying but I don't know another way to add files to you extension.

Comment: The other issue is that the database is stored in the Documents directory of one Target which cannot be accessed from the Todays Extension target.

Comment: This is another question

Answer (score 0):

As per Zubair's links below:

- Create an Application Group (for example group.com.yourcompany.app) and assign it to both your App and your Widget
- When opening your document, to get the NSURL for it, use for example:

  ```
  NSURL *storeURL ;

  storeURL= [[[NSFileManager defaultManager]
              containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:@"group.com.yourcompany.app"]
             URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourdatabase.sqlite"];
  ```

It is not strictly necessary to use a common framework, but it avoids code duplication.

Answer (score -1):

- You have to create an embedded framework to share code between your app extension and its containing app.
- To enable data sharing, use Xcode or the Developer portal to enable app groups for the containing app and its contained app extensions.

Here are apple Documentation Links

[Adding App group](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingAppSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH4-SW19)

[Handling Common Scenarios in App & extentions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html)

that discribes everything you need.

Comment: Embedded framework is not required, and he don't talk about data sharing but code files sharing.

Comment: @David'mArm'Ansermot To share the code, you have to use embedded framework, thats what i said